# How to Pass Sig from Alloy to Java and execute alloy model from Java

Tags: java, alloy, declarative

I have built an alloy model where I have put all my system logic. I want to do a large scale analysis. For doing that, my logic is to use Java to read the data file, then pass those data to Alloy to check whether those met the constraint I defined in the Alloy or not. To do that, my logic is to create sig object using those data and pass those to Alloy.

As my system model is complex, I am trying to summarize my problem using the following code-

```
sig A{
val: Int
}

sig B{
chunk: Int
}


fact {

    A.val > 10 && A.val < 15
}
```

Now, I want to pass the following sig object and run command from Java.

```
sig C{

name: String
}

run {} for 4
```

How can I pass that code? I am following this link  https://github.com/ikuraj/alloy/blob/master/src/edu/mit/csail/sdg/alloy4whole/ExampleUsingTheAPI.java . But not able to figure it out.

Comment: I believe the answer of this question might be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31121785/using-alloy-api-to-provide-custom-instances-to-alloy-analyzer

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a branch [pkriens/api](https://github.com/AlloyTools/org.alloytools.alloy/pull/83) in progress that makes this quite easy. Look at the testcases in the [classic test](https://github.com/AlloyTools/org.alloytools.alloy/blob/pkriens/api/org.alloytools.alloy.classic.test/src/test/java/org/alloytools/alloy/classic/test/AlloyImplTest.java) project.

We're working on integrating this in the master branch soon (before the end of 2019).